# Getting error extracting xml element from clob column

Tags: xml, xslt, plsql

getting null values I was trying to get xml element but not able to extract values of project and from
`"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="ns0 xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <emailRequest xmlns="http://egs.att.com/EGSService">
            <xsl:attribute name="project" namespace="" select="'MYWORLD'"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="region" namespace="" select="'RNSALL'"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="letterType" namespace="" select="'BBUDO100'"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="customerType" namespace="" select="'C'"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="ns0:bbuRequest">
                <xsl:attribute name="language" namespace="" select="fn:string(@language)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <retryIndicator>
                <xsl:sequence select="'N'"/>
            </retryIndicator>
            <ban>
                <xsl:sequence select="'9999999999'"/>
            </ban>
            <header>
                <xsl:for-each select="ns0:bbuRequest/ns0:destinations/ns0:emailAddress1">
                    <to>
                        <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
                    </to>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="ns0:bbuRequest/ns0:destinations/ns0:emailAddress2">
                    <to>
                        <xsl:sequence select="fn:string(.)"/>
                    </to>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <from>
                    <xsl:sequence select="'att'"/>
                </from>
            </header>
            <body>
                <templateData>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ns0:bbuRequest">
                        <dataField>
                            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'thresholddate'"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="string((string-length(string(ns0:thresholdDate)) > 10)) = 'true'">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(string(ns0:thresholdDate), 0, 11)"/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="string(ns0:thresholdDate)"/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </dataField>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </templateData>
            </body>
        </emailRequest>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>"`

```
select  EXTRACT(xmltype(column),
                             '//from') from table
                             where rownum <5


select XMLTYPE(xslt).EXTRACT('//emailRequest/@project','xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"').GETSTRINGVAL(),xslt  from edd_egs_config
where rownum <2
```

Tried above but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell Oracle the both used namespaces:

```
SELECT utl_i18n.unescape_reference(XMLTYPE (xslt).EXTRACT ('//from/xsl:sequence/@select', 'xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://egs.att.com/EGSService"').GETSTRINGVAL (), xslt
  FROM edd_egs_config
 WHERE ROWNUM < 5
```

and change the path and namespaces in the second one:

```
SELECT utl_i18n.unescape_reference(XMLTYPE (xslt).EXTRACT ('//emailRequest/xsl:attribute[@name="project"]/@select',  'xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://egs.att.com/EGSService"').GETSTRINGVAL (), xslt
  FROM edd_egs_config
 WHERE ROWNUM < 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: the Value of the Project should only be MYWorld but if I am using the second query then its giving me  <xsl:attribute xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" name="project" namespace="" select="&apos;MYWORLD&apos;"/>  and also the value of from should be only ATT but the query giving the entire string

Comment: @Neha The queries are changed . You have literals in the values. Shouldn't be 'ATT' and 'MYWORLD'

Comment: I have updated the first query to select EXTRACT(xmltype(xslt), '//from/xsl:sequence/@select','xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://egs.att.com/EGSService"') from edd_egs_config  and getting "&apos;att&apos;" how to just get att and get rid of everything else

Comment: @Neha see the queries. They are changed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ...only last issue is the xmls are not symmetric. There are 3 types of xml in the table that you solved, second if I use above queries fn:concat('MY', 'WORLD')  because the xml is like <xsl:attribute name="project">
     <xsl:sequence select="fn:concat('MY', 'WORLD')"/> and the 3rd one which is giving error  ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00225: end-element tag "n:templateData" does not match start-element tag "xsl:if"
Error at line 69
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 272
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: You can make a function to replace fn:concat.  fn:concat is XSLT command. The whole document is done to be used with XSLT. I do not know what you are trying to achieve. About the third, get the xml document from the record and check if it is a correct xml document;

Comment: I need to pull the values of project and from the xml column and create one report.

Comment: To have 'WORLD'  or WORLD in select= is different. The first will get the string WORLD and set in the output and the second will search for tag <WORLD> in the input and set the result in output.  You can easy make some function to extract the result from fn:concat, but what will be, when there is some other XSLT function or path? When you search for constants, make an XML and use Oracle XmlTransform function and than use the result to extract your values